# Is the review audit system broken? Only receiving audits!

Tags: bug, review, review-audits

As of **3:48 PM MST on May 22**, I am getting nothing but review audits.

[image: Really?]

I did fail one audit on First Posts, but then I go to Late Answers and I only get audits? I've tried refreshing the page.

This is also occurring on the LQP queue - I managed to max out my 20 reviews on audits!

[image: LQP's]